# How to add a property to the sealed class Arc

Tags: c#, properties, extends, sealed

how can I add two new properties to the sealed Arc class.
I want to extend the class with a double property to hold a double value and a string property to hold the name of the object.
My first try was via the Tag property but this can only hold the double value OR the object name.

The problem is that I created a new user control with 43 arc objects and when the mouse entered an arc another control shows up the value and the name of the entered segment. So every arc uses the SAME MouseEntered function and I want to get the informations via the "object sender".

I hope anyone has a nice idea.

Comment: Why not cast the sender to Arc, then you know which object raised the event?

Comment: Cause the Arc haven't the properties Value and ArcName.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. It's sealed. Either:

1. Create a new class that *contains* an `Arc` as a property.
2. Store a tuple or some other object in `Arc.Tag`.
3. Decorate the Arc with attributes

For your particular problem, I would suggest #2 above or to store a `Dictionary<Arc, blahblahblah>` or `Dictionary<string, blahblahblah>` (by name) and look up the info you need. #1 is a lot of overhead wrapping all the methods and properties you need for drawing, and probably more hassle than it's worth.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the *composite* pattern.

```
class SuperArc
{
   Arc Arc { get; set; }
   // other properties.
}
```

Comment: Ok but how can I add the SuperArc to my control XAML file?

Comment: I tried like this within the XAML: <myNamespace:SuperArc.Arc ..> but the compiler say that the member "Arc" is not recognized or is not accessible. I already made the class public also the Arc property. So where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend sealed clases.

Try creating your own class and having Arc as a class member, and expose this member functions.

Best regards.